# special symbols in .net and IndexOf

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I found an interesting bug, maybe even in .net (haven't try this in mono yet).

`IndexOf()` method of string instance is returning signed values (-1 or lower) for certain special symbols,

for example I had a string which contained some special unicode characters and somewhere inside of this string was colon which I was looking for. `Calling IndexOf(" :")` for a line that surely contains `" :"` returned signed value

I will try to paste this string here, but given the special symbols it may be hard:

`hitchcock.freenode.net 322 petan #hobbiton 5 :ˁ˚ᴥ˚ˀ > Good luck axa!`

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: What does your use of `IndexOf` look like?

Comment: I will paste the source code... hold on

Comment: ":hitchcock.freenode.net 322 petan #hobbiton 5 :ˁ˚ᴥ˚ˀ > Good luck axa!".IndexOf(":") This ststement is giving me corect result.. that is 0.

Comment: Can't reproduce either.

Comment: I cannot replicate the error. I get 0 as output. Both in C# interactive and in a Console Application.

Comment: works fine, win7, .net 4. what version of .net are you using and what versions do you have installed?

Comment: Which .NET version/x86 or x64/OS are we talking?

Comment: the full source code is here: https://github.com/pidgeonproject/pidgeon/blob/master/Protocols/irc/IRC.cs#L227 at this line it happens to me while parsing some 110 000+ lines from /list command on freenode network. However all of these lines are guaranteed to contain " :" which I am looking for, even this line for which it returns invalid result

Comment: @Petr can you put together a short, self-contained reproducible example of your question? This could be an arithmetic error in that large body of code.

Comment: Removing the first colon, just `"hitchcock.freenode.net 322 petan #hobbiton 5 :ˁ˚ᴥ˚ˀ > Good luck axa!".IndexOf(":")` gives me -1 instead of 45...hmm..

Comment: I think that despite the example by @Fung is not ultimately identical, it also points to same bug

Comment: @Fung try using `IndexOf(":", StringComparison.Ordinal)`

Comment: It probably has to do with the fact that the bear's left ear (`ˁ`) is a modifier. `"hitchcock.freenode.net 322 petan #hobbiton 5 :ˁ˚ᴥ˚ˀ > Good luck axa!".IndexOf(":ˁ")` does find the combined character. I'm not a Unicode expert, so I don't know what the next step is.

Comment: @MvanGeest correct, using ordinal comparison should give the correct result.

Comment: @MvanGeest ah ok, sorry for false alarm then, does it mean it's not a bug in .net bug in source code of my app? How can I make IndexOf() work properly on these modifiers and treat them as a regular character

Comment: `":ˁ".Contains(":")` is `true`, but `":ˁ".IndexOf(":")` is `-1`. o_O

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser, ideone [reports the results as 45](http://ideone.com/6cioIK) but [visual studio reports -1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NKJzV.png)

Comment: Search for the character instead of the string. e.g. `.IndexOf(':')` instead of `.IndexOf(":")`. That works and returns 45. Mind you, doesn't really help if you want to find `" :"`... :-/

Comment: Seems it could be a bug in right-to-left vs. left-to-right scripts in the same string, in which case the result/bug may be locale specific.

Comment: @Corak: `Contains` seems to use the Ordinal comparison whereas `IndexOf` uses the current culture. Don't know who thought that was a good idea.

Comment: @JulienLebosquain - oh, you're right, `Contains(string value)` is basically just a wrapper for `IndexOf(value, StringComparison.Ordinal) >=0`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is documented on the [BCL Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2008/11/04/what-s-new-in-the-bcl-in-net-4-0-justin-van-patten.aspx)

`IndexOf()` does a culture invariant comparison by default.

Note this in particular:

> UPDATE for .NET 4 Beta 1 In order to maintain high compatibility between .NET 4 and previous releases, we have decided to revert this change.  The behavior of String's default partial matching overloads and String and Char's ToUpper and ToLower methods now behave the same as they did in .NET 2.0/3.0/3.5.  The change back to the original behavior is present in .NET 4 Beta 1.  We apologize for any interim confusion this may cause.  **We continue to recommend being explicit about the string comparison behavior you want, by always specifying a StringComparison value for the methods on String that accept it.**

You should use the [String.IndexOf Method (String, Int32, StringComparison)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224424.aspx) overload:

For example:

```
IndexOf(":", StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

Comment: This is a good answer, especially because it say that everyone should use the version with StringComparison by default. I didn't know that and not doing so may result in unpredictable bugs like the one I had. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I see that some people want to close this question for some reason, so I will answer it before that happens :-)

Thanks to answers in comments by @vcsjones it seems to be related to locale settings, and can be fixed by changing

`text.IndexOf(" :")`

to

`text.IndexOf(" :", StringComparison.Ordinal)`

This may be a poor answer, but better than nothing...

Comment: What is your current culture?

Comment: en-US according to locale settings